# How to create a .bat file which compares the files in a folder with a xml file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I want to create a .bat file which compares the files in a folder with a xml file which is already having file names. It should not look for the order.
I will give folder path and xml file. 
The output I want is the list of files missing in the folder

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Edit your question to show us the code you have already tried and we'll tell you why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
@echo off

set "xml_file=c:\xml.xml"
set "directory=c:\dir\"

for %%$ in ("%directory%*") do (

  fc "%xml_file%" "%%~f$" >nul 2>nul && (
     echo "%xml_file%" and 
     echo "%%~f$" are identical
     color
  ) || (
     echo "%xml_file%" and 
     echo "%%~f$" are NOT identical !!!
     color
  )

)
```

change the path to the file and the directory at the beginning .